# Removing outlier data points from frequency-domain signal

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, denoising, complex

Hello signal processing stack exchange,

I have a complex frequency-domain signal representing the impulse response of a physical system over some range of frequency space. As an artifact of the simulation, some of the points are clearly off from what would otherwise be a smooth and Kramers-Kronig-obeying curve. Any recommendations on how to interpolate this curve while entirely ignoring these outliers?

[image: Frequency-domain signal with outliers]

Comment: How do you know that these points are outliers?

Comment: The result as shown isn't physical, but an artifact of the way the result is simulated.